# AWS IOT subscribe timeout exception

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have been using the AWS IOT python sdk for developing a cloud based iot software as a part
of a larger solution.However I frequently get the subscribe and publish timeout exceptions after some time on every run. Though i don't see a pattern here i am able to receive the messages published for some time duration.

How do i fix this issue so that i do not get those exceptions?

Is there any parameter that i have to set to prevent the IOt Subscription issue?
Or is there any additional setup needed to be done on the cloud?

Thanks in advance.